# Copy single field of all objects in array in single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wanted to optimize my code removing a `for-loop`.

```
    groupFieldNames = [];
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        groupFieldNames.push(data[i].groupFieldName);
    }
```

`data` is an array of objects, each having 4 fields.

[image]

I am interested in the one identified as `groupFieldName`.

Is there a way to avoid the loop and directly push the fields in the array?

**EDIT:**

I went with @Yosvel Quintero suggestion (to all the guys suggesting the map solution, he was the first one), and checked the performance.
With a data array having ~60k objects I've got:

- 3ms using `map`;
- 11ms using `for-loop`

Not bad.

Comment: Array.prototype.map()

Comment: You can use `.map` instead, but if you're looking for optimal efficient code, not much can beat a `for` loop...

Comment: You can use `map`, or `forEach`, whatever, it will iterate, just the loop won't be in your code, but you cannot avoid it.

Comment: Don't know your requirement but maybe you can keep the complete object and wherever you need groupFieldName, simply use object destructure {groupFieldName} = obj; or in methods methodName({groupFieldName}){//}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const groupFieldNames = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    groupFieldNames.push(data[i].groupFieldName);
}
```

To:

```
const groupFieldNames = data.map(o => o.groupFieldName);
```

Comment: As @sjahan pointed out, this still counts a loop, even if you cannot see it.
I was looking for something like mem-copy or stuff like that. But i see the elegance in what you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively use Array's built-in **[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** here as follows -

```js
var data = [
 { id: 1, groupFieldName: 'abcd' },
 { id: 2, groupFieldName: 'pars' }
];
var groupFieldNames = data.map(obj => obj.groupFieldName)
console.log(groupFieldNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

```js
var groupFieldNames = [];
var data=[{groupFieldName:'a'},{groupFieldName:'b'},{groupFieldName:'c'}]
  console.log(data.map(x=>x.groupFieldName))
```

You can also use `forEach`

```js
var groupFieldNames = [];
var data=[{groupFieldName:'a'},{groupFieldName:'b'},{groupFieldName:'c'}]
data.forEach(x=>groupFieldNames.push(x.groupFieldName))
  console.log(groupFieldNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the following way:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 66, groupFieldName: 'test', other: 'other'},
  {id: 66, groupFieldName: 'test2', other: 'other2'}
];

const groupFieldNames = data.map(({groupFieldName}) => groupFieldName);
console.log(groupFieldNames);
```